# Directly highlight one text range in RichTextFX

Tags: java, javafx, richtextfx

I'm currently trying to display the contents of a file in RichTextFX and then highlight a specififc character range on a line with a red background do indicate a problem with this lines.

My code displays everything neatly, but unfortunately I get no highlighting.

**code:**

```
    InlineCssTextArea textArea = new InlineCssTextArea();

    textArea.setParagraphGraphicFactory(LineNumberFactory.get(textArea));
    textArea.setMinHeight(200.0);

    textArea.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("parser.css").toExternalForm());
    try {
        List<String> yourFileLines = Files.readAllLines(file.toPath());
        textArea.replaceText(yourFileLines.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    textArea.setStyle(0, 0, 10, "error");
    textArea.setEditable(false);
```

**parser.css:**

```
.error {
    -rtfx-background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: The `setStyle` method does not accept Style Class. This works : `textArea.setStyle(0, 0, 10, "-rtfx-background-color: red;");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [documentation](http://fxmisc.github.io/richtext/javadoc/0.8.2/org/fxmisc/richtext/GenericStyledArea.html#setStyle-int-int-int-S-) the `InlineCssTextArea#setStyle` take directly the css property in parameter.

Thus, in your case it would be `textArea.setStyle(0, 0, 10, "-rtfx-background-color: red;");`.

---

**Note** that if you want many component with the same styles, the styleclass name is cleaner, and the best aproach (actually to my mind it is almost always the best approach). And by reading [this](https://github.com/FXMisc/RichTextFX/wiki/Text-Styles:-Inline,-Style-Class,-and-Custom-Style-Objects#applying-styles), if you want use class name you should choose the `StyleClassedTextArea` instead of the `InlineCssTextArea`. Indeed `StyleClassedTextArea` accepts StyleClass as parameter of its method `setStyle`. (see the example [below](https://github.com/FXMisc/RichTextFX/wiki/Text-Styles:-Inline,-Style-Class,-and-Custom-Style-Objects#style-class-pattern)).